# Small printer+scanner with very good support for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, printer, ubuntu, scanner

I search a small printer+scanner device for Ubuntu.

Which device has very good support for Ubuntu?

I want plug+play, I don't want to edit config files by hand or execute complicated shell commands to get it working.

Required features:

- LAN (optional WLAN) access
- Printing (A4 size is enough)
- Scanning
- Black/White printing is enough - Color is not needed
- Size: Not much bigger than 40cm x 40cm x 30xm

Boring background:

I have Brother DCP-7055W. The hardware is great: Scanner and Printer in one device and small. Perfect match. Except: Installing the drivers is a pain.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04 the scanner does not work any more.

I want to buy a new device instead of investigating how to get it working. I loved fixing errors like this in the past. But now I have wife, family and other hobbies.

Comment: Have you tried [updating the driver](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp7055w_us_eu_as&os=128)? You didn't specify that you had, and Brother is pretty good about this. It's entirely possible that will solve your issue, and you can avoid the expense of replacing an otherwise-functional printer (and the electronic waste associated with its disposal)!

Comment: You can also link to [the main download page](http://web.archive.org/web/20171110150815/http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp7055w_us_eu_as&os=128#SelectLanguageType-625_0_1) in the same way. The Wayback machine will update the page if it is still available. In any case, more detail in your answer would probably be appreciated by any future readers.

Comment: @Alpha3031 And yet if Brother revamps their site, it'll be a mirror of a stale page that links to stale drivers. The breakage you're trying to prevent tells whoever comes across the link that they should look for the newest version of the page, since when it comes to things like software outdated is, in many cases, worse than none: you think you've solved a problem but end up with software that has a security vulnerability that was fixed in a newer version (for example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68539/discussion-between-alex-and-alpha3031).

Comment: No I did not try to update the driver. I just want it to work. I want to buy a device that works. That's what this question is about. Even it would work, it does not solve this question, since the procedure to install the brother driver is much to complicated for me.

Comment: @guettli You use Ubuntu, yet updating a driver is too much for you? I humbly suggest a Mac for your next computer. (No shame in it; I use one myself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend a HP printer, specifically the [HP LaserJet Pro M130nw.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N9YOAZ6) Amazon claims to sell it for $99 once you add to cart.

HP has always had the best support on Linux [[1]](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1cjwez/printer_support_is_there_a_brand_that_has_good/)[[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102995/what-is-the-best-printer-for-ubuntu)[[3]](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers), and the current open source drivers – which are in the [default Ubuntu repository (main)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hplip&searchon=names&suite=all&section=main),* and may even be installed by default^ – claim full support for the M130 series [[4]](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). Linux is also listed as a compatible OS on the [specs page](http://www8.hp.com/pk/en/products/printers/product-detail.html?oid=9365256#!tab=specs)

It has 802.11 b/g/n as well as 100Base-T Ethernet (and USB 2.0,of course). Print output is 600 dpi maximum, with "FastRes" pixel doubling. Scanning is 600 dpi Colour, 1200 dpi Mono. Unfortunately, there is no autofeeder for the scanner. If you want one, you'll have to pony up for the next higher model. Auto duplex, single pass scanning and colour printing are all at far higher price points

Recommended page volume is 150 to 1500 pre month for both Print and Scan, though maximum duty cycle is 10 000 pages per month.

Its minimum dimensions are 398 × 288 × 231 mm, minimum being when all trays are closed, etc.

---

*"main" means a Canonical maintained package. It likely has the best support.

^if it isn't, just `sudo apt install hplip` in a terminal or search for it in Synaptic or Software Centre. `apt` has a nice progress bar.

Also, I'm assuming that laser Mono is preferred over inkjet colour. There may be a relatively affordable inkjet multifunction that also fit the requirements.

Comment: @guettli No worries, I'm glad to help. Hope you come back next time with another question or an answer! Our site is still very much growing, and every user counts.

Comment: I received the device today. Printing worked out of the box: Very nice. Unfortunately scanning does not work at all. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/977202/hp-laserjet-allinone-scan-does-not-work

Comment: @guettli Damn. That looks like a network module error. You might end up having to fiddle around with the config a little. It might work over USB though. Would you be willing to run a cable to your Ubuntu computer and using the network for any other computers? It looks like lots of people have SNMP issues, unfortunately. [\[1\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531918/why-is-snmp-broken)[\[2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467712/php-snmp-cannot-find-module)[\[3\]](https://thejoyofstick.com/blog/2012/12/01/installing-snmp-mib-files-in-linux-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) You might want to tag ...

Comment: ... with [snmp] and [mib] to get the right people to see it. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: I could get scanning to work on Ubuntu 17.04, but scanning works very good with the "HP Smart (HP AiO Remote)" Android App. I  have this all-in-one-device: HP LaserJet Pro MFP M130nw.